# Is it possible to register an ".er" domain?

Tags: domain-registration, cctld

Where could I go to register a `.er` domain?

Comment: I found this "webpage": http://www.afridns.org/er/tld_er.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. [It is not available for registration at this time.](http://www.rwgusa.net/er.htm) [More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.er)

Comment: One year later, and .ER still doesn't appear to be available.

Comment: no news on .er domain names yet :(

Comment: bump, its march 2013 and still no love from eritrea. i bet a zillion people are waiting to register their perfect whatev.er domain ...

Comment: Friendly dead link alert!

Comment: Do we know why it's not available for registration? Is it related to the political situation in Eritrea?

Comment: Wow pretty crazy that in 2019 it is still unavailable.  There's money just sitting there, they could just contract it out to some other authority on a yearly basis and make money without having to actually do any of the management work.

Comment: The regime in Eritrea is extremely paranoid, and has no interest in interacting with the outside world. They don't have elections, and most of the population are little more than slaves. Supporting this regime financially would be ethically dubious at best, though I know many people won't care.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible to register .er right now (Dec. 2016).

One way to check how difficult is to register within a domain extension is to perform a search in google like "site:.er". For .er, you can see that google has detected only 10 domain names, and most of the are from the government.

Comment: 7 years later. It's still the same.