# How to register a .er domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to register a “.er” domain. If so, how?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13064/is-it-possible-to-register-a-er-domain-if-so-how)

Is there anyway to register a .er (for Eritrea) domain?

I can't find information about, either registrants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems after more than a year, **[this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13064/is-it-possible-to-register-a-er-domain-if-so-how)** is still valid for your question.

Anyway, see these links:

- [How to Register an .er Domain Name](http://www.ehow.com/how_6805273_register-_er-domain-name.html)
- [I want to register a .er domain...](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?713866-I-want-to-register-a-er-domain-and)

Also according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.er):

> Registrations are at third level beneath names such as .com.er and .org.er

Comment: Eritrea is not a happy place, and it's doubtful that will change any time soon. Wikipedia: "...Reporters Without Borders classified the media environment in Eritrea at 178 out of 178, the lowest possible rating and below that of totalitarian North Korea at 177. According to the BBC, "Eritrea is the only African country to have no privately owned news media", and Reporters Without Borders said of the public media, "[they] do nothing but relay the regime's belligerent and ultra-nationalist discourse... state-owned news agency censors news... Independent media have been banned since 2001."

Answer (score 10):

As a former domain registrar (so no, not selling) and as a not too helpful answer, the only information available on Eritrean domains that I would trust comes from [the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/er.html).

Both [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/er.html) and [the International Telecommunications Union (ITU)](http://www.itu.int/ITU-D/membership/portal/index.asp?Name=1226) list the registry for .er as being run by [EriTel](http://www.tse.com.er) - but their website does not appear to exist.

The evidence would suggest, at this moment, you cannot register .er domains (or even third-level domains, in .com.er etc) - even the bucket-shop registration sites do not offer it!